# How to get compare exchange to accept my variables?

Tags: c++, types, c++14, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'm attempting to mitigate race conditions on a simple prediction feature in a library API (FUSE3) implementation that I have no control over. To do this I want to use `std::atomic<>::compare_exchange_weak` as early in my function callback as possible:

```
struct fdflag
{
    // ...
    std::atomic<unsigned long long> read_seq_offset_pred;
    // ...
};

std::unordered_map<int, struct fdflag> fdflags;

static int read(const char* path, char* buffer, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info* fi)
{
    if (fdflags[fi->fh].read_seq_offset_pred.compare_exchange_weak(offset, offset + size)) // *
        fdflags[fi->fh].sequential_reads++;
    // ...
}
```

However, gcc isn't letting me do that, complaining (on the line marked `*`):

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::__atomic_base::__int_type& {aka long long unsigned int&}' to an rvalue of type 'std::__atomic_base::__int_type {aka long long unsigned int}

I've tried using `const_cast<off_t&>(offset)` on the first parameter but it gave me a similar error message.

How do I get `compare_exchange_weak(T&, T)` to accept my parameters<sup>(without adding too much overhead or breaking the function signature)</sup>?

Comment: What is `off_t`?

Comment: It looks like `compare_exchange_weak(T&, T)` really expects a lvalue as a first parameter. Bizarre casts aren't a solution. What you can do is change `read` signature: `(..., off_t& offset, ...)` but of course you'll need to provide `offset` as an lvalue

Comment: @papagaga That wouldn't change anything.  Inside the function `read` `offset` is a lvalue (it has a name)

Comment: @NathanOliver True. My mystake

Comment: Do you get the same error message on this mcve? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b47dfc526d1884ed

Comment: @NathanOliver That compiles with the given command, but not when I change it to c++14 which I'm using.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast What about this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e35074e2a9e251e6

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes that compiles.

Comment: What is the type of `off_t`?

Comment: @NathanOliver According to `types.h` it's `long int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your atomic stores a `unsigned long long`.  That means the signature for `compare_exchange_weak` is `compare_exchange_weak(unsigned long long&, unsigned long long)`.  Since `off_t` is a `long int` you cannot bind that to the reference parameter.  You either need to store a `off_t` in the atomic variable, change your function to take a `unsigned long long`, or copy `offset` in a `unsigned long long` inside the function and pass that to `compare_exchange_weak`

Comment: I would write:

std::atomic<off_t> read_seq_offset_pred;

That is why there the typedef is.